# Correctly referencing a newly computed column with the same name

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause

I am using Snowflake, and I have a couple of old tables that I am using to generate a new table. The new table has to have the same column names as the old tables. To make the new table, I do a join. Simplified a little, the SQL looks like this -

```
create table NEW_TABLE as
  select
    f(A.abc, B.abc) as abc
  from OLD_TABLE A
  join OTHER_TABLE B on <conditions>
  where f(A.abc, B.abc) > 0
```

It works. But the `where` part is not good because I have to recompute `f(A.abc, B.abc)`. If I alias `abc` as something else like `select f(A.abc, B.abc) as abc2` I can simply reference `abc2` in the `where`.  However, then `NEW_TABLE` will have a column named `abc2` which is wrong. If I don't alias `abc`, then anytime I reference `abc`, it uses table A's value for `abc` instead of the newly computed one. What is the right solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using:

```
select
  f(A.abc, B.abc) as abc
from OLD_TABLE A
join OTHER_TABLE B on <conditions>
where abc > 0;
```

Condition `abc > 0` cannot use the alias defined at the select level as it is overshadowed by column name.

Using different alias than already existing column is a solution,but does not provide value as it is not anticipated column name.

```
select
  f(A.abc, B.abc) as alias_not_existing_in_table
from OLD_TABLE A
join OTHER_TABLE B on <conditions>
where alias_not_existing_in_table > 0;
```

SAS's SQL dialect support [calculated](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/a002294533.htm) keyword designed exactly for such scenario. Pseudocode:

```
select
  f(A.abc, B.abc) as abc
from OLD_TABLE A
join OTHER_TABLE B on <conditions>
where calculated abc > 0;
```

---

An alternative approach is using LATERAL JOIN and explicitly prefix the expression:

```
SELECT
   s.abc
FROM OLD_TABLE AS A
JOIN OTHER_TABLE AS B
  ON <conditions>
,LATERAL (SELECT f(A.abc, B.abc) AS abc) AS s
WHERE s.abc > 0;
```

This way there is explicit alias that allows to distinguish between A.abc and a new computed value.

Comment: [Snowflake Ideas](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) - search for: `Lateral column aliasing - new keyword to distinguish between original column vs expression named same as column`